# I can use a python code to control LED connected to Raspberry, but using C it doesn't work

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm just using standard examples. So the code are definitely correct. But I don't know why C code does not work

```
 /**********************************************************************
* Filename    : 1.Blinking_LED
* Description : Make an led blinking.
* Author      : Robot
* E-mail      : support@rexqualis.com
* website     : www.rexqualis.com
* Update      : Tim   2019/12/02
**********************************************************************/
#include <wiringPi.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#define LedPin      0   //the pin to connect the led
int main(void)
{
    // When initialize wiring failed, print message to screen
    if(wiringPiSetup() == -1){
        printf("setup wiringPi failed !");   //catch error and break
        return 1;
    }
    pinMode(LedPin, OUTPUT);// Set LedPin as output to write value to it.
    while(1){
        // LED on
        digitalWrite(LedPin, LOW);  //write Low to ledPin
        printf("...LED on\n");   //log the led on
        delay(1000); //1000ms delay to blink
        // LED off
        digitalWrite(LedPin, HIGH); //write high to ledPin
        printf("LED off...\n"); //log the led off 
        delay(1000);   //1000ms delay to blink
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  #the pin libaray of raspberry
import time  #the time libaray of system time
LedPin = 17  #the BCM pin connect to LED
def setup():
    # Set the GPIO modes to BCM Numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
    # Set LedPin's mode to output,and initial level to High(3.3v)
    GPIO.setup(LedPin, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
# Define a main function for main process
def main():
    while True:
        print ('...LED ON')
        # Turn on LED
        GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
        print ('LED OFF...')
        # Turn off LED
        GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
# Define a destroy function for clean up everything after the script finished
def destroy():
    # Turn off LED
    GPIO.output(LedPin, GPIO.HIGH)
    # Release resource
    GPIO.cleanup()
# If run this script directly, do:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    try:
        main()
    # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the program destroy() will be  executed.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()
```

Above is the C code and python code

the compile and  of C code is also standard with pemmision:

```
gcc 1.Blinking_LED.c -o Blinking_LED.out -lwiringPi
sudo ./Blinking_LED.out
```

This code is supposed to make a LED light blinking. When I'm running the python code, it's all right. But when running the C code, on terminal everything is ok. The printing are all good. Nothing unexpected happens. But the LED does nothing.

I've solved this problem, it is the problem with GPIO permission.  As in this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/ .

use this command

```
sudo usermod -a -G gpio <username>
```

also, run the code by

```
./Blinking_LED.out
```

instead of

```
sudo ./Blinking_LED.out
```

Still, it is strange for me why python does not have this issue.

Comment: What exactly does not work of your code? If you get an error, please post it, otherwise post the expected vs the obtained behaviour.

Comment: This code is supposed to make  a LED light blinking.  But, when I'm running the C code, it does not do anything at all. But when I'm running the python code, it's all right.

Comment: Do you at least get '...LED on' to print?

Comment: Or anything printing to the terminal for that matter?

Comment: When running the C code, on terminal everything is ok. The printing are all good. Nothing unexpected happens. But the LED does nothing.

Comment: Maybe you're using the incorrect pin. Otherwise, it's time to attach gdb to the process and see what's going on.

Comment: @hit Please add all requested information to the question. Which pin is the LED connected to? Is it correct that you have `#define LedPin 0` in C and `LedPin = 17` in Python?

Comment: Thank you. Because C and python have different libraries to support gpio. I've looked for the tables, they are the same pin

Comment: Thank you for your help. IThank you again for your kindly help

Comment: Perhaps you could flesh out the solution with the GPIO permission stuff in the form of an answer to your own question? It's perfectly fine and encouraged to answer your own questions here. It might help future readers facing the same problem.

Comment: Yes, have done that, thank you!